# Get historical wind forecast data from GFS for a specific location

Tags: python, noaa, grib-2

I need historical windspeed & direction forecast to train an ML model. GFS seems to be the best solution since they have 6 months of forecasts publicly available: https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/global-forecast-system/access/grid-004-0.5-degree/forecast/

Since each grib2 file is roughly 150 mb it would mean downloading a huge amount of data just to throw away most of it. There is an option to download more recent data with a filter applied: https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/txt_descriptions/grib_filter_doc.shtml
but its only available 10 days back. Is there any way to download a filtered version of the 6 month old data?

Comment: maybe this is useful? https://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/NCEP_Global_Best.html

Comment: Thanks Bert, seems like a Goldmine! I'm just wondering how to interpret the data since I'm getting just one pair of windspeeds for each long/lat pair for a given timestep. I expected to see multiple forecast value pairs for each time step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: Under https://pae-paha.pacioos.hawaii.edu/thredds/catalog/ncep_global/runs/catalog.html you can download GFS model forecast runs for each day at 12:00 with 3 hours time steps and 8 days into the future. Selecting "NetcdfSubset" will give you the option of downloading the specific data for a selected region.

A big thanks to J. Maurer (University of Hawaii) for helping me!